# How to overflow the image inside a div in the top and bottom and not just in left and right?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the image overflow not just in left and right but also in the top and bottom. 
I'm not sure if the problem is in my css or html.

```
.sectionForm {
        margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1914/1914882.svg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 190% auto;
    }
```

```css
.sectionForm {
        margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1914/1914882.svg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 190% auto;
    }
    .sectionForm form {
        width: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 66px 0 50px 0;
    }
    footer {
        height: 1500px;
    }

    .form-container input {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
        padding: 26px 0;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #4F4F4F;
    }
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<div class="sectionForm">
        <form>
            <div class="form-container">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Nome">
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="E-mail">
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Assunto">
           
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just needed to add padding to it

> ```
> background-size: 160% auto;
> padding: 112px;
> ```

```css
.sectionForm {
        margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1914/1914882.svg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 160% auto;
    padding: 112px;
    }
    .sectionForm form {
        width: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 66px 0 50px 0;
    }
    footer {
        height: 1500px;
    }

    .form-container input {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
        padding: 26px 0;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #4F4F4F;
    }
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<div class="sectionForm">
        <form>
            <div class="form-container">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Nome">
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="E-mail">
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Assunto">
           
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```